# How to create index in desc order in code first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Want to create index by `EmployeeCardNumber` (text) in descending order.

So the sql script should be like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employees ADD CONSTRAINT
IX_Employees_EmplyeeCardNumber UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    EmployeeCardNumber DESC
)
```

In `IndexAttribute`, there is an `Order` property, which is an integer???

Here is my fluent api:

```
        var indexAttr = new IndexAttribute("IX_Employees_EmplyeeCardNumber")
        {
            IsClustered = true,
            IsUnique = true,
            Order = 1 // probably should be removed since we are using a composite key.
        };

        Property(c => c.EmployeeCardNumber)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(indexAttr))
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRequired();
```

So the question is, how to define "DESC" in this code first approach?

Comment: As a side note `Order = 1` is the order of the keys for a composite key.

Comment: You are right, Erik. I am not using composite key, so I guess it can be either omitted or 1. But where is the place to make it DESC on the indexed key?

Comment: If I knew the answer I would put it in the answer location, I did some minimal research and didn't find the answer myself, but I'm not confident in my own research that EF doesn't support Desc Indecies just yet.